# Why does increasing availability of microstates compensate for increased energy of products in an endothermic spontaneous reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm wrestling with the idea right now of processes that are both endothermic and spontaneous.I understand that there must have been an associated increase in entropy.

How does an increase in "microstates" compensate for the fact that a chemical reactions products have overall "more energy" than the reagants?

Edits: Clarified question

My attempt: Two closets have same volume, except one has shelving and the other doesn't. The closet with shelving is "preferred" because it is able to "handle" more shoes ("energy") than other closet because there are more ways to arrange those shoes (on the shelves).  The shelved closet with 10 shoes is more "organized" than the nonshelved one with 8 shoes. Which means, in my analogy, Gibbs is a measure of energy "organization."

Comment: Melting ice at above the freezing point is endothermic and spontaneous.

Comment: Every endothermic reaction you could observe qualifies and that's a whole type - virtually infinite.

Comment: Edited question! Thanks for feedback!

Comment: The shelved closet will have greater entropy because of all the many ways that you can arrange the shoes, i.e. particles can be placed many more ways into many energy levels than into a few levels level with the same overall energy. This means that as $G=H-TS$ and if $S$ increases then $G$ becomes smaller and more negative. It is the multiplicity of arrangements of particles (or shoes) in the energy levels that is important here.

Comment: Energy distributes itself among the available microstates. The greater the number of microstates, the greater is the statistical probability that the system will find itself in an arrangement corresponding to the macrostate—in this case, the endothermic product. Therefore, the spontaneity of the endothermic reaction is fundamentally driven by this statistical probability, which results from the nature of energy to distribute itself among all available microstates and the endothermic product possessing a preponderance of such microstates in the system.

Comment: @Blaise I think I understand. So you're saying that spontaneity is all about the possible arrangement of microstates. And if the majority of available microstates are higher energy, than the product will be statistically higher energy. So because a molecule has a ton more microstates available in the gas state, than the solid or liquid state, molecules will spontaneously evaporate. Blaise, I encourage you to write up an answer with examples so I can upvote!